# Library archive has main defined

Tags: c++11, linker-errors

I am using a library file that has a main function defined.When I compile and link, I get the linker error
"Multiple definitions of main" first defined here. It points to the library.a file.
Can you please advise as to how I can direct the linker to ignore the library's main and use the one in the CPP file.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have control over what goes into the .a file?

Comment: What library are you trying to use? What OS? How do you link?

Comment: This is a library from a hardware manufacturer, that I cannot disclose, I apologize. The operating system is Ubuntu Linux. I am just using g++ for now to complete the prototype, but I will use CMAKE once I have this working. Thank you.

Comment: I want to thank everyone. I had built the library wrongly with all the samples as well. This lead to the archive file having multiple mains of the samples. Once I rebuilt the archive without the samples, the problem went away. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrectly built the SDK library. Details of the error are above. I apologize for the confusion.